# Display a random quote from MySQL without repeating

Tags: mysql, sql, random, repeat

I am trying to make a quote page. I would like it to show a random quote every time the page loads but also have a "Next Quote" button that changes to another random quote without repeating, unless of coarse you have gone through all the quotes. I have been trying for a few days now and haven't gotten anywhere past loading a random quote on page load. If someone could please help me. Thanks.

Comment: How many quotes are there? Is this loading in a web page? What languages and/or frameworks are you using (both front-end and back-end)

Comment: There will be about 100 quotes. I am somewhat new to web development. I was planning on using mysql for the database of quotes. Then just html and php. I am open to javascript as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

1. Mark which ones the user has already seen, then when you do a SELECT, filter out the ones the user already saw.
2. Pre-create the random order, then keep track of which quote the user last viewed. For example, quote #8. You then show quote #9 next time. Whether y

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar with a "WHERE id NOT IN" but how do you keep track of which quotes the user has seen already. I am still new to php/mysql. Perhaps to difficult a task for a beginner? If someone could whip up a working sample that would be great. Not sure how much work that would be though. Thanks for the replys.

Comment: Each user should have there own unique ID associated with them. Each quote should have it's own unique ID. Create a table containing user id and quote id, then left join them. SELECT quote FROM quotes LEFT JOIN seen_quotes ON quotes.quote_id=seen_quotes.quote_id AND seen_quotes.user_id=# WHERE seen_quotes.quote_id IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming web pages and a limited number of quotes, I would just load them all into the html on the page load, and then loop through them with a slider.

What you could also do, is just load one randomly into the page and then provide the rest via xml or json. That way if the user doesn't have javascript (though rare) or a screen reader (accessibility for disabled users) they will hear / see only one quote, and then with javascript you can load in the rest of the quotes.